# Change data in component by configfile outside vue compiled package

Tags: vuejs2

I have a js file with vuejs app

For example after do npm run watch-poll i want to change the title with a configfile

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

App.js

```
import adrescheck from './components/adresCheck'
Vue.component('adres-check', adrescheck)
import Adrescheck from './Adrescheck.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    render: h => h(Adrescheck)

});
```

Adrescheck:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ title }}
        <adres-check standalone="true" showButton="true"></adres-check>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                title: 'Test'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Edit:

Store.js

```
import config from "../../../../../../../../config.js"
state: {
    ...config,
}

getters: {
    hello(state){ return state.hello; },
```

Vue comp:

```
        },computed: {
            //your other computed properties
            ...mapGetters(["hello"])
        }
```

Template:

```
{{ hello }}
```

Or created() this.hello returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, you could try the following (in `app.js`) :

```
fetch("/js/config.js")
.then(res => res.text())
.then(eval)
.then(config => {
  /*
  Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
  and use the config for your app
  */
});
```

For instance, in your `config.js` :

```
({
  hello: "world"
});
```

Although I have to say that `eval` really is unsafe and generally bad practice. You might want to rethink how your app is designed (e.g. Use a preprocessor/transpiler along with a bundler/build system, import your config via the import mechanism they propose).

For instance, with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) along with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) you could have (once properly configured)

```
//dev/config.js
export default {
  hello: "world"
};

//dev/app.js
import config from "./config"
/*
Wait for the DOM to be fully loaded
and use the config for your app
*/
```

One of the many advantages of using a bundler is that you can also use Vue's [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) as well as having absolute control over your app without ever having to use tricks and unsafe utilities like `eval`.

**EDIT**
You seem to be using `vuex`, you could use your config file to initialize a property (or properties) in the store's state, create getters and simply use `mapGetters` in your components to access said property(ies)

```
//where you configure you store
import config from "path/to/config"
import Vuex from "vuex"
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    //your other states
    ...config
  },
  getters: {
    //your other getters
    hello(state){ return state.hello; }
  }
});

//in a component
import { mapGetters } from "vuex" 

export default {
  //everything else
  computed: {
    //your other computed properties
    ...mapGetters(["hello"])
  }
}
```

I highly suggest reading [Vuex's guide on core concepts](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) for more information on how to use vuex.

**EDIT 2: Dynamic loading**
If I understand correctly you don't want to statically load the config file but instead load it for every page (so that you can change it manually and still observe changes without recompiling). You will therefore need to use actions with mutations in addition to a getter :

```
//config.js
({
  hello: "world"
})

//where you configure you store
import Vuex from "vuex"
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    //your other states
    hello: ""
  },
  getters: {
    //your other getters
    hello(state){ return state.hello; }
  },
  mutations: {
    setHello(state, value){ state.hello = value; }
  },
  actions: {
    loadConfig(context){
      return fetch("path/to/config")
      .then(r => r.text())
      .then(eval)
      .then(config => {
        context.commit("setHello", config.hello);
        return config;
      });

      /*
      or if you use JSON
      return fetch("path/to/config")
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(config => {
        context.commit("setHello", config.hello);
        return config;
      });
      */
    }
  }
});

//in a component
import { mapGetters } from "vuex" 

export default {
  //everything else
  computed: {
    //your other computed properties
    ...mapGetters(["hello"])
  }
}

//app.js
import store from "path/to/store"
store.dispatch("loadConfig").then(_ => {
  /*setup your app when the dom is fully loaded*/
});
```

One disadvantage is that we're back to using `eval`. However, if you can use JSON instead of plain js for your config then it would be safer.
Now that you have the `loadConfig` action you can also dispatch it whenever you want to reload the config, you just need access to the store to do so.

Comment: i have changed my description what i want. I want to change for example title by a configfile.js. So after npm run dev / watch-poll How can i do that?

Comment: Yes i am using vuex, where can i read that solution for inclusing/importing a config.js

Comment: I just added an example

Comment: i imported mapgetters, but how to use hello?!

Comment: Simple, `mapGetters` maps the selected getters to a computed property. Simply use `this.hello` in a render method or `hello` in a template, just like any computed property

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your error (maybe my latest edit would help you, regarding how to instantiate the store), see [this vue codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/o96q99qmpq)

Comment: Thats not what i want, the config file has to be standalone, because when hello: world gonna be edit to hello:you then i have to npm run dev again. If i change the file via ftp the config has to react to that change

Comment: So, dynamically loading the config on page load would do the trick?

Comment: if i download the config file and change this hello: "world" to hello: "you" and upload i want to display you.

Comment: Do you have to update only on page load or do you also have to update already loaded pages?

Comment: in the component template i want to see the change {{hello}} returns after edit the file on the server to "you"

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the dynamic loading part

Comment: I would really encourage you to use JSON for configuration files instead of plain JS, it can eliminate a lot of security issues